# Rights modules uses a different application instance

Tags: yii, rights

I'm developing a Yii application which uses several modules including Rights module for access control. They all are residing in the same "modules" folder and configured in the same config/main.php file. And application has only one entry script.

However I noticed that Rights module uses a different app session while all other modules uses another app session. Because of this reason user session is not shared with Rights.

Has anyone encounter such issue with yii modules? please help. Thanks!

my config file:

```
'rights'=>array(
            'debug' => true,
            'superuserName'         => 'Super Administrator', // Name of the role with super user privileges.                       
            'authenticatedName'     => 'Customer', // Name of the authenticated user role.
            'userIdColumn'          => 'id', // Name of the user id column in the database.
            'userNameColumn'        => 'username', // Name of the user name column in the database.
            'enableBizRule'         => true, // Whether to enable authorization item business rules.
            'enableBizRuleData'     => true, // Whether to enable data for business rules.
            'displayDescription'    => false, // Whether to use item description instead of name.
            'flashSuccessKey'       => 'success', // Key to use for setting success flash messages.
            'flashErrorKey'         => 'error', // Key to use for setting error flash messages.
            //'baseUrl'             =>'/rights', // Base URL for Rights. Change if module is nested.
            //'layout'              => 'rights.views.layouts.main', // Layout to use for displaying Rights.
            //'appLayout'           => 'application.views.layouts.main', // Application layout.
            //'cssFile'             => 'rights.css', // Style sheet file to use for Rights.
            'install'               => false, // Whether to enable installer.
        ),
```

Comment: there should be some problem with code. can you paste some code so i can judge? but i think different session is not problem because according to my understanding it is not possible.

Comment: I think it's more likely that the rights module has not been instantiated when you try to access it ... if, for example, in your controller access rules, you are referencing the user module, you would need to make sure the module has been referenced by the UserIdentity first ...

Comment: hi guys, thanks for comments. I've updated the question with my config details. rights module also included as any other module in the system. So strange that rights is using a completely different app instance while all other modules use a common app instance. I confirmed  this by checking the app id (Yii::app()->id)

Answer (score 0):

After trying for two days I found the solution.

I noticed that it uses two different key prefixes (stateKeyPrefix) in system. One for Rights and another one for other modules. This can be configured to use single key prefix in main config file.

```
'user'=>array(
            'class'=>'RWebUser',
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true, // enable cookie-based authentication
            'stateKeyPrefix'=>'f298d9729c7408c3d406db95a9639204', // some random value
    ),
```

Hope this will help someone with the same issue.